# two page layouts into one view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I would like some advice on this matter. I have a view page that will display a number of users. One view is to display users in a grid (gallery like) of their images. Second view is to display the same users but by their name in a list layout. I will have a toggle button on the page to switch between the two. What is the best way to go about it? Having two separate view pages or have a partial view of some sort?

**Update Code after suggestion below**

```
<div data-bind="template: {name:'grid-template'}"></div>
<div data-bind="template: {name:'list-template'}"></div>

<script style="float:left"  type="text/html" id ="grid-template">
    <section " style="width:100%; float:left">
    <section id="users" data-bind="foreach: Users">
        <div id="nameImage">
            <figure id="content">
                <img width="158" height="158" alt="Gravatar" data-bind="attr:{src: GravatarUrl}"/>
                <figcaption>
                    <a title="Email" id="emailIcon" class="icon-envelope icon-white" data-bind="attr:{'href':'mailto:' + Email()}"></a>
                    <a title="Profile" id="profileIcon" class="icon-user icon-white"></a>
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
            <p data-bind="text:Name"></p>
            </div>
        </section>
    </section>
</script>

<script style="float:left" type="text/html" id="list-template">
        <div data-bind="foreach: Users">
            <div style="width:60%; float:left; margin:10px; height:58px">
                <img style="float:left; margin-right:5px" width="58" height="58" alt="Gravatar" data-bind="attr:{src: GravatarUrl}"/>
                <p style="height:58px; float:left; vertical-align:central" data-bind="text:Name"></p>
                <a style="float:right"  title="Profile"  class="icon-user icon-black"></a>
                <a style="float:right"  title="Email" class="icon-envelope icon-black" data-bind="attr:{'href':'mailto:' + Email()}"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
</script>
```

**Knockout Script File**

```
$.views.User.UserViewModel = function (data) {
        var self = this;
        self.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
        self.Email = ko.observable(data.Email);
        self.ContentRole = ko.observable(data.ContentRole);
        self.MD5Email = ko.observable(data.MD5Email);
        self.GravatarUrl = ko.computed(function () {
           return 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/' + self.MD5Email() + '?s=300&d=identicon&r=G';
        });
        self.renderMode = ko.observable('grid');
        self.displayTemplate = ko.computed(function () {
            return self.renderMode() + '-layout-template';
        });

    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I like having clean isolated small little Partial Views especially if it is going to be regular HTTP POST.
However, based on the assumptions I am making below, I think I can suggest a better implementation design.

#### My Assumption

You have

1. `Index.cshtml` **Parent** view to display a list Users.
2. JSON object array containing your list of Users
3. Based on what I see, you are using KnockoutJS.
   Read the [KnockoutJS Template Binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html) especially the **"Note 5: Dynamically choosing which template is used"** part.

It kind of makes it easier to do what you are doing if you are using **KnockoutJS** or something similar.
You simply have toggle between the two rendering templates.

```
<script type="text/html" id="gallery-layout-template"> ... </script>
<script type="text/html" id="listing-layout-template"> ... </script>

<div id="divOutputContainer"
     data-bind="template: { name: displayTemplate, foreach: users }"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    // I am just writing out a dummy User array here.
    // Render out your User Array JSON encoded using JSON.NET.
    var myUsers = [
        { "id" : 1, "name": "User 1" },
        { "id" : 2, "name": "User 2" }
    ];

    // here is your KnockoutJS View Model "class"
    function MyKoViewModel(users) {
        var self = this;
        self.users = ko.observableArray(users);

        // Toggle this renderMode observable's value
        // between 'listing' and 'gallery' via your Toggle button click event handler
        self.renderMode = ko.observable( 'gallery' );

        self.displayTemplate = function(user) {
            // this will return 'gallery-layout-template' or 'listing-layout-template'
            return self.renderMode() + '-layout-template';
        }
    }

    ko.applyBindings( new MyKoViewModel( myUsers ) );
});
</script>
```

So with that technique, you **don't need to make an AJAX call every time** to refresh the view with a different rendering template.
You have all your data that you want to display as a client-side JavaScript KnockoutJS view model.
Then, just switch the client-side rendering template using KnockoutJS.

Must more efficient :-)

#### NOTE

I have a feeling, you might have to use the [ko.computed()](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) for the `MyKoViewModel`'s `displayTemplate()` function like this.

```
self.displayTemplate = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.renderMode() + '-layout-template';
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for all the great information! I will try it out and will get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: I've taken your suggestion into consideration. The only thing i have left is to create a toggle button for the two views i would like to create a grid button and list button that when one is pressed it will display. Currently i have both the grid and list showing on the page.